# Symfony swagger add annotation for content type

Tags: symfony, annotations, swagger, nelmioapidocbundle

I would like to add `*/*` in my controller annotations Content-Type, I tried:

`* @SWG\Get(produces={"*/*","application/json"})`

this doesn't work :

`* @SWG\Get(produces={"*\//*","application/json"})`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found something that work.
I add in nelmio_api_do.yaml :

`nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        produces:
            - '*/*'
            - application/json`